# FPDF error: Template does not exist! fpdf

Tags: php, fpdf

So I am trying to modify a pdf template with php.

I looked around and found out most people use FPDI and I gave it a try.

So What i did was

```
include('pdf/fpdf.php');
include('pdf/fpdi.php');

// initiate FPDI
$pdf = new FPDI();
// add a page
$pdf->AddPage();
// set the sourcefile
$pagecount = $pdf->setSourceFile('pdf/menu_blanka.pdf');
// import page 1
$template = $pdf->importPage($pagecount);
// use the imported page as the template
$pdf->useTemplate($template, 0,0,0);
```

And I constantly get this error "FPDF error: Template does not exist!".

Can you guys help me out ?

Comment: Vasil, I hope you have found a solution. I am having the same issue when trying to recreate the FPDI simple example here: https://manuals.setasign.com/fpdi-manual/the-fpdi-class/examples/

Comment: Does the menu_blanka.pdf file exist in the pdf directory? I assume your script is located in the parent directory of the pdf directory?

Comment: Try calling ``$pdf->AddPage();`` *after* ``$pdf->setSourceFile('pdf/menu_blanka.pdf');``

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I have achieved this in a project of mine. Works fine ..

```
require_once 'pdf/fpdf.php';
require_once 'pdf/fpdi.php';

$pdf = new FPDI();

$pdf->setSourceFile('/path/to/source.pdf');

$pdf->AddPage();
$tplidx = $pdf->ImportPage(1);
$pdf->useTemplate($tplidx, 0, 0, 0);                    

$output = $pdf->Output('output.pdf', "S");
```